# Can anyone help for getting response by entering username and password?

Tags: android, json, apache, passwords, restful-authentication

I'm new in android development. So plz help to add http in this code to get response when i click on submit button. I've done all validations of username and password. But i don't know how can I use JSON RESTFUL in this code. So plz help me to solve this problem.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 private static final String SERVICE_URI = "http://www.safepestadmin.com.au/windex.php?itfpage=login";
    public  EditText edittext_username, edittext_password;
Button button_submit;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  



    edittext_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_edittext_password);
    edittext_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_edittext_username);
    button_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button_submit);




    button_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               String email = edittext_username.getText().toString().trim();
               String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
               String pwd = edittext_password.getText().toString();



               if (email.matches("")   && pwd.matches(""))
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a username and a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else if (email.matches(emailPattern)    && pwd.matches(""))
                   {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

                  else if (email.matches("") && pwd.length()>0) 
                  {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }         

                  else if (!email.matches(emailPattern) && pwd.length()>0) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  else if (!email.matches(emailPattern)  && pwd.matches("")) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  else if (email.matches("alam@gmail.com") && pwd.matches("12345")) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  else {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter registered email and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }

        }       
    });

}

   }
```

Comment: I do not understand the question, please be clear what you want

Comment: I want to use the above url by entering the username and password

Comment: that url gives json which contains username and password?

Comment: yess...username alam@gmail.com and password 12345

Comment: He want to login by hitting that web service url with filling params as username and password and getting json response.

Comment: Thanks Manish. Can anybody help me in it?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi you can see my answer below , I give the main idea, if you need code I can give

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

- Send your password and username to server
- In your server keep password as encrypted in your database
- When username and password comes to webservice you can get users password and decypte it and **compare** with the password which comes from **client**
- I the passwords are matched you can send client just **true** if wrong you can send **false**
- In client if it comes **true** from webservice you can give permission to enter person

client code:

### you can create a class like this:

```
public class web_api_get  extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

     @Override
    public String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        HttpParams params2 = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params2, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params2, "UTF-8");
        params2.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params2); 
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]+""); 
        try {       
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {  
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
           // Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
          } 

            } catch (Exception e) { 
            }

        return builder.toString(); 
    } 

}
```

**And then you can call it like this :**

String result= new web_api_get().execute("your link here include your password and username").get() ;

and then the `result` is getting you **true** or **false**  from webservice

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the piece of code in AsyncTask Class.

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Context... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(("http://URL/Login_Auth? Username="+username+"").replace(" ","%20"));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
    String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Log.d("====Response====",""+responseData.toString());
    }
    }
```

In Log.d() you get the Response from URL.

Answer (score 0):

use aysctask and send username and password to server. use this code and call this asyctask after clicking on login button

```
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //Create new default HTTPClient
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Create new HTTP POST with URL to php file as parameter
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/myteamapp/index.php"); 

            //Assign input text to strings
            username = etUser.getText().toString();
            password = etPass.getText().toString();



            //Next block of code needs to be surrounded by try/catch block for it to work
            try {
                //Create new Array List
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                //place them in an array list
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "username"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));

                //Add array list to http post
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                //assign executed form container to response
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //response from the PHP file

                //check status code, need to check status code 200
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                    //assign response entity to http entity
                    entity = response.getEntity();

                    //check if entity is not null
                    if(entity != null){


                        //Create new input stream with received data assigned
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                        //Create new JSON Object. assign converted data as parameter.
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                        //assign json responses to local strings
                        String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("user");//mySQL table field
                        String retPass = jsonResponse.getString("pass");

                        //Validate login
                        if(username.equals(retUser)&& password.equals(retPass)){ //Check whether 'retUser' and 'retPass' matches username/password 

                            //Display a Toast saying login was a success
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } else {
                            //Display a Toast saying it failed.

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }


                }


            } catch(Exception e){

               // e.printStackTrace();
                //Display toast when there is a connection error
                //Change message to something more friendly
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               return null;
            }



            return null;
        }
    }
}
```